# Fourier Transformation with wrong result in amplitude spectrum, why?

Tags: python, time-series, signal-processing, fft, spectrogram

I try to make a magnitude spectrum with a signal looking this this:

[image]

Why do I not get any sparks in the Magnitude spectrum? Or what is wrong with my data? Or why is the peak only at 0?

I used a quite long data set, but here is a sample of the signal:

```
s = [45772.47797743, 45792.20303892, 45772.47797743, 46374.99865567, ... 45671.71873548, 45651.16006596, 45630.4722909 ]
```

And the code:

```
from scipy.fftpack import fft, fftfreq, fftshift

s = np.array(id1.u_motion)
Fs= 4

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=3, ncols=2, figsize=(7, 7))

# plot time signal:
axes[0, 0].set_title("Signal")
axes[0, 0].plot(t, s, color='C0')
axes[0, 0].set_xlabel("Time")
axes[0, 0].set_ylabel("Amplitude")

# plot different spectrum types:
axes[1, 0].set_title("Magnitude Spectrum")
axes[1, 0].magnitude_spectrum(s, Fs=Fs, color='C1')

axes[1, 1].set_title("Log. Magnitude Spectrum")
axes[1, 1].magnitude_spectrum(s, Fs=Fs, scale='dB', color='C1')

axes[2, 0].set_title("Phase Spectrum ")
axes[2, 0].phase_spectrum(s, Fs=Fs, color='C2')

axes[2, 1].set_title("Angle Spectrum")
axes[2, 1].angle_spectrum(s, Fs=Fs, color='C2')

axes[0, 1].remove()  # don't display empty ax

fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Can anyone help to find the reason for why i dont get any spikes in the amplitude spec??
Thanks so much!

Comment: If there are no periodic components in the signal that are stronger than all the others, you won’t get any peaks in your frequency spectrum.

Comment: But isnt there a periodic signal in the blue plot?

Comment: I don’t know, could be random.

Comment: Remove the DC portion of your data, just by subtracting the average of the data vector from each point.

Answer (score 0):

Your signal is a very good DC signal with low noise. The log plot reveals that.

In general, in cases like yours, a very high DC component hides the weak high frequency contributions. The equivalent in my example is in red.

Possible solutions are to remove the DC (blue curves) or plot the log of the spectrum (bottom row) as you have done already.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as p
%matplotlib inline

T=3 # secs
d=0.04 # secs
n=int(T/d)
print(n)
t=np.arange(0,T,d)  
fr=1 # Hz
y1= np.sin(2*np.pi*fr*t) +100
y2= y1- np.mean(y1)

f1=np.fft.fftshift(np.fft.fft(y1))
f2=np.fft.fftshift(np.fft.fft(y2))
freq=np.fft.fftshift(np.fft.fftfreq(n,d))

p.figure(figsize=(12,10))
p.subplot(231)
p.plot(t,y1,'.-',color='red', lw=0.5, ms=1)  
p.plot(t,y2,'.-',color='blue', lw=0.5,ms=1) 

p.xlabel('time (sec)')
p.ylabel('amplitude (Volt)')
p.subplot(232)
p.plot(freq,np.abs(f1)/n,color='red')
p.title('very high DC dominates other components')
p.xlabel(' freq (Hz)')

p.subplot(233)
p.plot(freq,np.abs(f2)/n)
p.xlabel(' freq (Hz)')

p.subplot(235)
p.plot(freq,np.log(np.abs(f1)/n),color='red')
p.title('very high DC dominates other components')
p.xlabel(' freq (Hz)')

p.subplot(236)
p.plot(freq,np.log(np.abs(f2)/n))
p.xlabel(' freq (Hz)')
```

[image]